# % in barplot() instead of count

Tags: r, bar-chart

I did a script to have a good barplot with barplot() on R

Is it possible to have on the y-axis the % and not the quantity (number of observations) ?
I would love to have the % without to change all of the script...

Thanks a lot

Comment: I used prop.table(g2) and it worked well

Comment: What have you tried? Please give us an example of what you have so far. [Here are some tips](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to do this.

Comment: I did like this: 
test$Hoursdecimal<-as.factor(test$Hoursdecimal)
g2<- table(test$Hoursdecimal)
g2<-prop.table(g2) 
g2<-g2*100
barplot(g2)

Answer (score 0):

`ggplot` has this option, but for `barplot()` I believe you will have to make a new variable that represents the percent and then feed that into `barplot()`